# undefined function apache_request_headers()

Tags: wp-cli

I'm trying to run the following command locally:

```
/usr/local/bin/wp plugin deactivate "EG Fulltext Search" --allow-root
```

And I get the error `undefined function apache_request_headers()`

Here is the wp info:

```
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.5.37
php.ini used:   /etc/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.24.0-alpha-95a84de
```

This is running apache on Centos 7.  Php is running as Apache 2.0 Handler.

I used the nightly version but I also get this error the latest stable release.

I'm really stuck on this at the moment and can't use the wp commands so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the plugin slug rather than a human readable name?

Comment: Thanks Andy!  You're right I had to use the slug to make it work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From quick search I cannot find calls of this function in neither WP core or WP CLI.

From quick check of [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) for it it seems that support for it in CLI context is (relatively) recent — starting with PHP 5.5.7.

You might want to check if your PHP up to date. Note that CLI might be running different/older PHP version from web server.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction.  I found the apache call in wp-config.php which was setting variables based on the x-forward-proto header existing.  I wrapped the code in a if function exists block and it works now!  :-)